# Sonarqube anaylsis on .NET project on remote server

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a .Net project (C#) and Sonarqube installed and configured on a remote server. How is it possible to do a Code analysis locally from my machine against the remote Sonarqube server?

I do not want to trigger the code analysis via Jenkins.

Is it even possible? I have the sonar-scanner downloaded on my local machine where the code resides. But I do not know how to proceed further.

```
Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
```

I think due to this warning there is no proper analysis on the project

Comment: does it matter where the code analysis run, that is it is for you important that there is a run un on the server or is your usecase to do the code analysis before the check in ?

Comment: have you looked at the SonarQube extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube?

Comment: The use case is to get the report on the remote sonarqube server. I got the server to do the analysis. But there is something more missing to do the task. I will update the question with the error